# Secure forwarding of 2FA SMS codes

Tags: mobile, account-security, sms

Do solutions exist for forwarding SMS messages whereby:

- the service provider stores no logs of messages
- login protection with google authenticator or comparable

Answer (score 3):

In short I think its unlikely - it would be a very niche solution.

There are [numerous services](https://www.greenbot.com/article/2102552/android/4-android-apps-that-put-sms-on-your-desktop.html) which support syncing of messages from a mobile to online clients - but these work by storing your messages to a database - you could use a dedicated mobile left somewhere secure with a mobile signal to receive the messages.

There are also various online services which allow you to receive SMS's to a dedicated number via their website.

> login protection with google authenticator or similar.

You want two factor for your two factor? :P

I think you are misunderstanding a couple of things. First is the purpose of 2FA. Second is the security (or lack thereof) of SMS. Two factor via SMS is not very secure - it is very easy to view an SMS while in transit (especially if you are within range of the same tower as the legitimate user). Its also not that difficult to clone a mobile SIM. You also need to realise you are inherently trusting a service provider as it is (your cell provider).

So either of the above options simply add an additional party to an already fairly insecure system.

The purpose of Two factor is a separate channel that an attacker needs to compromise. Obtaining a username/password combination and intercepting an SMS require two very different resource and skill sets. Unless you are a high value target expecting dedicated resourceful attacks (in which case frankly you shouldn't be using SMS in the first place), you have to ask what is the probability of my credentials for a service being breached AND the same attacker identifying me as using an SMS relay service / lifting the two factor code from it before it expires. Unless you have used the same credentials for both services i'd argue extremely slim.

Comment: Yeah i understand that. SMS itself as just the additional layer is alright. My concern is that if my username/pass is compromised - an attack vector to get a username/pass for the service which i use to forward my SMS messages may be the same.

Comment: @user1935987 - Unless you have reused credentials (which clearly in this case completely defeats the point of 2FA) then for this to happen both services are compromised in the same way at the same time by the same attacker - who then decides to cross reference the SMS service for 2FA codes. It also assumes that either one of the providers is not correctly storing passwords or that your passwords were easy to reverse. Good password discipline makes far more of a difference here than 2FA.

Comment: Sure not reused credentials :) Taking in account that both services are accessed from PC/laptop - any keylogger / backdoor / whatever gets an access to the data from browsers - is likely to get credentials from both services. Am i wrong about it?

Comment: If they have root access to the machine you log into the primary service from they can just lift the active session token as soon as you have authenticated via 2FA. Meanwhile im sure one of the online SMS platforms has a reasonable mobile interface - so you can use a smartphone over WiFi if you are still concerned.

Comment: I realize it's 4 years later, but for the last year or so I've been using a tiny ESP32-based device to forward my SMSes to a private Slack channel. Just published instructions how to build it on https://sms2slack.com/assemble.